# Scraping com python

Tags: python, regex

Como capturar uma ou mais frases de um site com Python e/ou expressões regulares?

Quero tudo que comece com

```
<p>&#8220; e acabe com &#8221;</p>
```

Exemplo:

```
<p>&#8220;frasefrasefrasefrasefrasefrasefrasefrase.&#8221;</p>
```

Como proceder?

Comment: A *regex* deu certo para você?

Comment: Não, nem o módulo beautifulsoup, acredito que por falta de conhecimento da minha parte.. Mas cheguei proximo do que queria com os dois.

Comment: Dependendo sobre o que é, acho que posso ajudar, se for algo que se encaixe nessa pergunta, edite, se não for crie uma nova pergunta explicando aonde você quer chegar. Se puder marque a resposta como aceita.

Comment: @QMechanic73 gostaria de marcar a resposta como aceita, como faço?

Comment: Para marcar uma resposta como aceita, clique na marca de verificação do lado esquerdo da resposta; sua cor mudará de cinza para verde. [Veja](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a expressão `#8220;(\w.+)&#8221` que vai corresponder a números e letras(minusculas e maiúsculas) e `.` que estiverem entre `#8220;` e `&#8221`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

dados = """<p>&#8220;Linha 1&#8221;</p>
<p>&#8220;Linha 2&#8221;</p>

<p>&#8220;Linha 3 &#8221;</p>
"""

regex = re.compile("#8220;(\w.+)&#8221", re.MULTILINE)
matches = regex.findall(dados)

if matches:
    print(matches)
# Saída: ['Linha 1', 'Linha 2', 'Linha 3 ']
```

Como você pode ver será retornado uma lista, para acessar um valor especifico  faça:

```
print(matches[0])
# Saída: Linha 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/X9NZvA)</kbd>

Nota: Expressões regulares não são recomendáveis para lidar com estruturas de arquivos *html/xml*, o correto seria utilizar um *parser*, como o [`Beautifulsoup`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2) que serve muito bem para esse propósito de *scraping*.

Veja um exemplo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com'
html = urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for li in soup.findAll('li'):
    for a in li.findAll('a'):
        print("%-45s: %s" %(a.text, a['href']))
```

Comment: A razão por nao se utilizar regex para parsear html é uma resposta bem famosa no stackoverflow em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454